# Rails - How to write a rendered page as a static HTML file?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, performance, caching

The homepage of my application is fairly heavy, it loads content from 6 different web-services on the fly & some of these are quiet slow, most of the data from these service providers & from our own CMS does not change at all during the day - only gets updated late at night.

For performance reasons I would like to write the entire page, which is generated by the /home/index controller/action, to a file in my public directory (/public/home/index.html) so that incoming requests for this page can bypass most of the Rails stack.

Any ideas on how this could be achieved?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the caching system of rails to do that.

Here an example (from [this](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/caching_with_rails.html#page-caching) guide):

```
class ProductsController < ActionController

  caches_page :index

  def index
    @products = Products.all
  end

  def create
    expire_page :action => :index
  end

end
```